# Research in functionality of open source and commercial game engine

Tags: game-engine

I'm gonna start my research in Functionality of open source and commercial game engines, but the problem is where to start. Or is this the right title to choose for a research topic?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 'Feasibility of Open Source and Commercial Game Engines'.

If I got you right, I think you may start from some famous open source projects' website like [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net).

Comment: thank u very much for suggestion could u do me another favor?
could u let me know where shall i start writing from or what shall i look for to start off?
Thanks

Comment: You may start missing with some commercial (demos) or open source engine and see what features they got to critique them, see what could be done to improve the engines in general, or you may make the whole research as a comparison between games which are based on game engines and games which are not. (definitely the games using engines will win that).